# Building a Tree from Breadcrumbs

Tags: scala

I need to transform

```
List("home", "mens", "clothing", "jackets")
```

into

```
List(
  "/home",
  "/home/mens",
  "/home/mens/clothing",
  "/home/mens/clothing/jackets"
)
```

This is what I have so far:

```
val nodes = Array("home", "mens", "clothing", "jackets")
val (rootNode, otherNodes) = nodes.splitAt(1)
val tree = otherNodes.foldLeft(rootNode) { (list, token) =>
    list :+ (list.last + "/" + token)
}
```

What do you think? any obvious problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need a variation of the [prefix sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) algorithm applied to your list. In Scala this can be accomplished with [scan](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List):

```
val xs = List("home", "mens", "clothing", "jackets")
xs.scan("")(_ + "/" + _).tail
```

Comment: Very nice! I didn't know about scan

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need to split the nodes to run this correctly..

consider:

```
val tree = (nodes.foldLeft("") { (list, token) => 
    list :+ (list.last + "/" + token)
}).tail
```

I could also imagine extracting the current binary operator into a separate function.

Aside from that this is really nice and clean